# How to access pure js value outside of a react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I want to access a js function value outside of react class. How can I do that.

Here is the function I want to access to

```
export function listConnectionNames() {
  let data = []
  let res = window.gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
     'resourceName': 'people/me',
     'pageSize': 10,
     'personFields': 'names,genders,birthdays'
   }).then(function(response) {
     var connections = response.result.connections;
     if (connections && connections.length > 0) {
       for (let i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
         let item = {
           "resourceName": connections[i].resourceName,
           "name": connections[i].names ? connections[i].names[0]["displayName"] : "",
           "gender": connections[i].genders ? connections[i].genders[0]["formattedValue"] : "",
           "birthday": connections[i].birthdays ? connections[i].birthdays[0]["value"] : ""
         }
        data.push(item)
       }
       return data
     }
   })
   return res
}
```

This is the react class I want to use that res value I got from that js function.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
```

I tried to use `window.res` to make it a global variable, but the react class cannot get the value, since it's a async call. What should I change to fix it

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the other answers, here's a more thorough answer that will allow you to see the data on the 2nd render when the state has been updated after the promise has resolved.

#### Updated List Connection Names

```js
export function listConnectionNames() {
  return window.gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
    'resourceName': 'people/me',
    'pageSize': 10,
    'personFields': 'names,genders,birthdays'
  }).then(function(response) {
    let data = []
    const connections = response.result.connections;
    if (connections && connections.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
        let item = {
          "resourceName": connections[i].resourceName,
          "name": connections[i].names ? connections[i].names[0]["displayName"] : "",
          "gender": connections[i].genders ? connections[i].genders[0]["formattedValue"] : "",
          "birthday": connections[i].birthdays ? connections[i].birthdays[0]["value"] : ""
        }
        data.push(item);
      }
      return data;
    }
  });
}
```

#### Example React Component

```js
import React from 'react';
import { listConnectionNames } from './where-ever-the-list-connection-name-file-is.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    listConnectionNames().then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        data,
      });
    });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return <div>Hello World</div>;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method to fetch data for your component to display:

[From the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. **If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   this is a good place to instantiate the network request.**

**Example:**

```
class App extends Component {


   constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchConnectionNames();
    }

    fetchConnectionNames = () => {
        window.gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
            resourceName: 'people/me',
            pageSize: 10,
            personFields: 'names,genders,birthdays',
        }).then(response => {
            const {connections = []} = response.result;

            const data = connections.map(({resourceName, names, genders, birthdays}) => ({
                resourceName,
                name: names ? names[0].displayName : '',
                gender: genders ? genders[0].formattedValue : '',
                birthday: birthdays ? birthdays[0].value : '',
             }));

             this.setState({data});
         })
     }

    render() {
        const {data} = this.state;

        if(!data) return <p>Loading...</p>;

        if(!data.length) return <p>No items...</p>;

        return (
            <ul>
                {data.map(({resourceName, name, gender, birthday}) => (
                    <li key={resourceName}>
                        <p>{resourceName}</p>
                        <p>{name || 'NO VALUE'}</p>
                        <p>{gender || 'NO VALUE'}</p>
                        <p>{birthday || 'NO VALUE'}</p>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Working example:

[image: Edit q3v6o9mxyw]

Answer (score 0):

Just call this function inside a class

class App extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const connectionNames = await listConnectionNames()
    this.setState({ connectionNames }) 
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the function.

I assume both functions/classes are in 2 separate files.

If you are using webpack you can import the function like this:

```
import { listConnectionNames } from "path/to/the/file"
```

and then you can just call that function like this:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = { result: null }
}

async componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    x: await listConnectionNames()
  }
}
```

If you are not using webpack you need to include both files in your html.

Also not that a function in a module file does not automatically get put into the global namespace/scope

Helpful resources: “JavaScript Modules: A Beginner’s Guide” @iam_preethi https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc